# Override groupdate Gem in Rails to return a hash of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, grouping

I am using the [groupdate gem](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) to group Events by day on event_start_time, which is a Rails datetime object. Is there anyway I can override the `group_by_day` function to return a hash with hashes containing the Event objects.

As per the documentation this is the hash you get when grouping by day.

> ```
> User.group_by_day(:created_at).count
>     # {
>     #   2013-04-16 00:00:00 UTC => 50,
>     #   2013-04-17 00:00:00 UTC => 100,
>     #   2013-04-18 00:00:00 UTC => 34
>     # }
> ```

What if instead I want to return a hash like the example below.

> ```
> User.group_by_day(:created_at).count
>     {
>     2013-04-16 00:00:00 UTC => { id: "1", location: "Sf",.., },
>     2013-04-17 00:00:00 UTC => { id: "40", location: "Gt",.., },
>     2013-04-18 00:00:00 UTC => { id: "100", location: "SD",..,}
>     }
> ```

In my view I would like to display these grouped by day Events. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the proper or similar result should be returned by `User.group_by_day(:created_at)` without `count`. Isnt it?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I have tried doing `User.group_by_day(:created_at)` without `count` but get a syntax error: `ERROR: column "events.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: SELECT "events".* FROM "events" WHERE (event_start_time IS N... ^`

Comment: Try user.group_by_day(...).to_sql and show result

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Thanks for the feedback. I am using postgresql in development. Not sure if `to_sql` will work .

Comment: To_sql is a common rails method

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I wasn't aware of that. Thanks.